# SQL query to show users that have null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL and I have a slight issue with my query that I have created, What I have done is created a query that will create a time summary of all of our staffs time recording on a particular day, currently the query works but what I need it to do is bring through a list of all of our users, not just filter by the users that did time recording on that day.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeTransactions.ChargeBasis = 'C' THEN TimeTransactions.QuantityOfTime/60/6 ELSE 0 END) AS ChargableUnits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeTransactions.ChargeBasis = 'N' THEN TimeTransactions.QuantityOfTime/60/6 ELSE 0 END) AS NonChargableUnits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeTransactions.ChargeBasis = 'C' THEN TimeTransactions.ValueOfTime ELSE 0 END) AS ChargableValue,   
    SUM(CASE WHEN TimeTransactions.ChargeBasis = 'N' THEN TimeTransactions.ValueOfTime ELSE 0 END) AS NonChargableValue,
    SUM(TimeTransactions.QuantityOfTime)/60/6 AS TotalUnits,
    SUM(TimeTransactions.ValueOfTime) AS TotalValue,
    Users.Code AS FeeEarner
FROM
    Users INNER JOIN TimeTransactions ON TimeTransactions.FeeEarnerRef = Users.Code
WHERE
Users.FeeEarner = 1 AND Users.UserStatus = 0 AND
 TimeTransactions.TransactionDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
 AND TimeTransactions.TransactionDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
GROUP BY
    Users.Code
```

I expect it to show users that did not do time recording on that day as showing 'NULL' in each row instead of removing them from the table.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it.

Use a CTE to build your user query and place your user related filter conditions in there, then left join this on to your time table and apply your time filter conditions there. This avoids left joining the 2 tables raw but then applying a filter on to the right table which forces an inner join under the hood.

EDIT:

This is a working example of what you are trying to achieve. I have greatly SIMPLIFIED the table structure as the columns referenced in the query supplied don't match the columns provided in the image samples. Also it looks like the query is trying to use a column alias in a where clause (which isn't possible in SQL server).

In the below example I've applied filtering on the timetransaction table in the common table expression and then left joined the user table on to that. This produces the following output.

[image]

You can see a zero is returned for users whose time transactions do not match the filtering condition, where using an inner join those users would not be returned at all.

With more comprehensive data examples (that represent the column structure and the expected output or something similar) we could work out a solution which would be far closer to cut and paste ready, whereas this example is simply that, an example of how I would construct a left join where filtering needs to happen in the table on the right hand side of the join.

Good luck, if you have any questions let me know.

```
declare @users table (
    userid int identity(1,1),
    username nvarchar(50)
);

declare @timetransaction table (
    timetransactionid int identity(1,1),
    userid int,
    quantityoftime int
);

insert @users
values
('SomeBody'),
('AnyBody'),
('SomeoneElse');

insert @timetransaction
values
(1, 7),
(1, 12),
(2, 5),
(3, 71),
(3, 4);

declare @userid int = 1;

with timetransaction as (select userid, quantityoftime from @timetransaction where userid=1)

select u.userid, coalesce(SUM(quantityoftime), 0) as total from @users u
left join timetransaction t on u.userid=t.userid
group by u.userid;
```

**Example of users table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DYZS.png)

**Example of time transactions table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbRhj.png)

Comment: Hi Dwight, really appreciate the help, I have copied in your query and I am now receiving the below error. ''Recursive common table expression 'users' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator. Not sure if I have copied it over correctly? I literally copied and pasted your query.

Comment: Hi GSLawrence, if you can provide a sample of the users table and the time table then I can write a working demo. It seems like you have pasted the query in to an existing cte or a batch with a cte of the same name which would be why the compiler thinks the query is trying to be recursive (when it isn't).

Comment: Hi Dwight, I have pasted the query into TaskCentre but I have converted the task that I have created into a SQL query so all that is contained in the query is the above. Not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN`.  But it is very important to get the filtering conditions right:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tt.ChargeBasis = 'C' THEN tt.QuantityOfTime/60/6 ELSE 0 END) AS ChargableUnits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.ChargeBasis = 'N' THEN tt.QuantityOfTime/60/6 ELSE 0 END) AS NonChargableUnits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.ChargeBasis = 'C' THEN tt.ValueOfTime ELSE 0 END) AS ChargableValue,   
       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.ChargeBasis = 'N' THEN tt.ValueOfTime ELSE 0 END) AS NonChargableValue,
       SUM(tt.QuantityOfTime)/60/6 AS TotalUnits,
       SUM(tt.ValueOfTime) AS TotalValue,
       u.Code AS FeeEarner
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN
     TimeTransactions tt
     ON tt.FeeEarnerRef = u.Code AND
        tt.TransactionDate >= dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND
        tt.TransactionDate < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
WHERE u.FeeEarner = 1 AND u.UserStatus = 0 
GROUP BY u.Code;
```

Notes:

- The conditions on `TimeTransactions` need to go in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE`.
- SQL Server supports the `DATE` data type.  There is no need to do arcane calculations using date differences to remove the time component from a value.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you for your help Gordon, I have pasted the above in and it is telling me there is an incorrect syntax near 'AND'. I might have to accept defeat on this one and study a little more! lol

Comment: This is working now, thank you very much for your help